# Run a Pre-Build Event only when Rebuilding

Tags: visual-studio-2010, batch-file, msbuild, makefile, nmake

I'm compiling a project which depends on a couple of other open-source projects (specifically, Zlib and LibTIFF), for which Windows makefiles (intended for use with nmake) are provided. I'd like to arrange things such that, whenever I perform a 'Rebuild' on my project, the open-source projects are also rebuilt with the appropriate configuration (Debug/Release, 32/64 bit etc.).

My own project is fairly straightforward but not trivial. I squandered my first few days by trying to figure out how to generate nmake makefiles of my own, either directly or using CMake. Despite having a reasonable amount of experience with GNU make, this caused me to lose the will to live. After coming out of rehab, I decided to stick with a Visual Studio project file for building my own project, and to define a 'Pre-Build event' to execute nmake on the supplier-provided makefiles for my open source libraries.

For example, in my Visual Studio 2010 project page for a 32-bit Release build, using the Intel C++ compiler, I write my Pre-Build Event command line as:

```
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Composer XE 2013 SP1\bin\ipsxe-comp-vars.bat" ia32 vs2010
cd ..\..\..\zlib-1.2.8
nmake /f win32\Makefile.msc zlib.lib
cd ..\tiff-4.0.3
nmake /f Makefile.vc lib
```

(I realise I could just as well put the above into a batch file, and call the batch file, but I don't want to give myself another file to keep track of). Anyway, this works great, except for one thing: if I decide to change my configuration, I'd like to execute an 'nmake clean' on the two libraries to ensure that they're rebuilt with my new configuration, something along the lines of:

```
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Composer XE 2013 SP1\bin\ipsxe-comp-vars.bat" ia32 vs2010
cd ..\..\..\zlib-1.2.8
IF "%BUILDACTION%"=="REBUILD" nmake /f win32\Makefile.msc clean
nmake /f win32\Makefile.msc zlib.lib
cd ..\tiff-4.0.3
IF "%BUILDACTION%"=="REBUILD" nmake /f Makefile.vc clean
nmake /f Makefile.vc lib
```

Unfortunately, I can't seem to identify any environment variable which satisifes the role of BUILDACTION here, nor can I see a straightforward way of defining one. So, is there any way of doing what I'm trying to do here, or am I on a hiding to nothing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Stijn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/128384/stijn) put me on the right track: the final solution was manually to add the following section right at the end of my .vcxproj file (immediately before the </Project> which formed the very last line):

```
  <Target Name="OnCleanOnly" AfterTargets="Clean">
    <Exec Command="call &quot;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat&quot; x86
                   cd ..\..\..\zlib-1.2.8
                   nmake /f win32\Makefile.msc clean
                   cd ..\tiff-4.0.3
                   nmake /f Makefile.vc clean" />
    <Message Text="Cleaning libraries" Importance="High" />
  </Target>
```

This ensures, as required, that the 'nmake clean' commands are run every time either 'Clean Solution' or 'Rebuild Solution' are selected from the 'Build' menu. This is *precisely* what I was hoping to achieve.

Answer (score 6):

Once you realise the `Rebuild` target is just a stub and actually consists of calling `Clean` follwed by `Build` (just like in a typical gnu makefile btw), the solution presents itself: use two seperate targets, one for Clean and one for Build. You can leave the pre-build event as-is, and add one for Clean. Open the project file in a text editor and add something like this at the end:

```
<Target Name="OnCleanOnly" AfterTargets="Clean">
  <Message Text="OnCleanOnly" Importance="High"/>
</Target>
```

This target will be called automatically when the `Clean` target is called. Which is the case when you do Clean or Rebuild from within VS, or by calling `msbuild myproject /t:Rebuild` on the command line for instance.

Note, you say *I realise I could just as well put the above into a batch file, and call the batch file, but I don't want to give myself another file to keep track of* but I wouldn't dismiss that idea so fast, as it does have the main advantage that you can test if the build event itself is ok simply by running the batch file. If you want to do the same for a target embedded in a project file, you have to fire up a command line, figure out which target to call exactly and run `msbuild projectfile /t:target` to test it. Much more work :) Also keeping track of files is the job of your versioning system so you shouldn't have to worry about it.

Comment: This looks promising, but the GUI doesn't seem to expose an opportunity for specifying a 'Post-Clean event' so it looks like I'll have to edit the .vcxproj file directly. There is some documentation for this (in fact, a great deal more documentation than I could find for nmake!) so I'll take a look at it.

Comment: Yes indeed you have to manually edit it. But fear not, it's pretty readable xml :] especially when using a text editor that recognizes it. Easiest is actually to edit the project file using VS itself since it has intellisense/autocomplete/... for project files. Or use SublimeText with the msbuild plugin.

Comment: I'm nearly out of the woods, but I could do with a bit of advice if you can give it. When I incorporated the XML item you suggested and added (on the line after <Message.. />) the line "<Exec Command="cd ..\..\..\zlib-1.2.8 (carriage return) nmake /f win32\Makefile.msc clean"/> (according to the documentation, carriage returns within an Exec Command are fine), I got the error message "'nmake' is not recognised as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file". It didn't object to the 'cd' command, but it seems to have lost the path to 'nmake'. Is there a way of fixing this?

Comment: Did you call `ipsxe-comp-vars.bat`? nmake is normally not on your PATH and I'm guessing ipsxe-comp-vars.bat sets all environment variables needed for a proper build. Create a batch file with the commands, execute it form a 'plain' command line (i.e. without calling ipsxe-comp-vars.bat or any of VS's xxvars.bat, run the batch file, check if that works . Only if it does, you should be able to use it with Exec.

Comment: Yes, that's it! I'd assumed that the 'native Microsoft' environment variables were already set, and that all ipsxe-comp-vars.bat was doing was to set the extra Intel-specific variables. Obviously this wasn't the case, and it turns out that calling either ipsxe-comp-vars.bat or (the Microsoft equivalent) vcvarsall.bat work just as well for ensuring that 'nmake' is recognised. I also had to escape the quotes which were required in the pathname. I'll post a separate answer in a moment to record the final solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the same by following below process:

1. Add the executable in your project
2. Right click ->properties of the executable.
3. Change "Item Type" to "Custom Build Tool"
4. Apply
5. Go to newly created "Custom Build Tool" tab.
6. Add your command in "Command Line" section.
7. Specify the name of output files generated by command line.
8. Select other option accordingly as per your requirements.
9. Click on "OK"
10. Do it for all of your files on which custom build is required for both Debug and Release configuration

Its Done!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can call your bat with an argument `R` if it's a rebuild and without if not. ie. `Yourbat.bat R` and then just test the argument (`%1`).

```
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Composer XE 2013 SP1\bin\ipsxe-comp-vars.bat" ia32 vs2010
cd ..\..\..\zlib-1.2.8
IF /i "%1"=="R" nmake /f win32\Makefile.msc clean
nmake /f win32\Makefile.msc zlib.lib
cd ..\tiff-4.0.3
IF /i "%1"=="R" nmake /f Makefile.vc clean
nmake /f Makefile.vc lib
```

I used the `/i` parameter that the `IF` stay case insensitive (you can use `r` or `R`)

Comment: Thank you, but I can't quite see how this helps unless I can cause the 'R' to be added automatically when I select a Rebuild rather than an ordinary Build. If, every time I want to do a Rebuild, I have to open up the project page and manually change "call YourBat.bat" to "call YourBat.bat R", then I'm not that much better off than if I just change the text of the batch file itself. And I'm  still stuffed if I forget to do it. The key requirement is to identify some variable by which the file can test automatically whether the user has requested a Rebuild or an ordinary Build.

Comment: What do the user differently when he call a rebuild as when he call a normal build ?

Comment: Under normal circumstances a Rebuild would occur when the user wants to switch from Debug to Release, or from 32-bit to 64-bit. It's at these times when a library rebuild is necessary to ensure that we don't end up trying to link a 32-bit Release project with a 64-bit Debug library, for example.